# Include link to (unit) test classes in JavaDoc

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, javadoc

Is it, or should it be, good practice to include links to (unit) test classes in the JavaDoc of a class?

I have not seen this so far but find it very helpful when jumping between class and test class(es). I also think test cases give good examples for usage of a class.

What are the arguments against linking test cases in the JavaDoc?

Comment: sorry, this was not intentional, your answer is fully satisfying to me ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely **not** good practice.

For one simple reason: the responsibility of production code is to its "production job". Production code is **not** responsible for providing information about your test setup! Sometimes it is *pragmatic* to have a package-protected method around that allows you to *inspect internal state* of your object - to make unit testing easier. But that is something you do to make testing **easier/possible**. Meaning: such things can be acceptable (when not going overboard) - but this idea is not.

And even when you ignore that: the "standard" practice is to have your unit tests in a distinct, **separate** package. So, you got two projects `prod` with class/package "x.y.Z", and `test` with "x.y.ZTest". And: **of course** there should be **only** a dependency from `test` to `prod` - but **not** in the other direction. And "true linking" (like `{@link SomeClass}`) in javadoc would require you to have such a dependency. You can't link to a class that can't be resolved by the compiler in your project setup!

Beyond that: if you follow the above recommended layout for your projects, then you **always** know: "if there is a test for class Z - then this test should be named ZTest". And any decent idea finds ZTest for you.

In other words: when I want to look at a test for a class in eclipse, then I simply double click the class name (to select that name); then I press "ctrl-shift-t" (open type) ... and eclipse presents two classes to me: Z and ZTest.

Long story short: instead of polluting your production code with information that doesn't belong there - make sure you are following standard procedures and have the **tools** at hand that solve such problems for you. The reason why *clean code* is important: one has to understand that **each** line in source code represents **costs**. People who have to fix bugs or enhance functionality have to read that line (probably very often). Therefore: anything that doesn't support the core responsibilities of a class - should not be there.

Comment: Methods/ fields, etc. that are there only for testing in production code is another matter of discussion. I think your strongest argument is the **dependency from production code to test code**, which is definitely not wanted.

Comment: @kerner1000 Well. I reworded that paragraph to mention your concerns. Let me know what else is missing that would prevent you from upvoting ;-)

Comment: .. the longer I think about it, the more I think our today's separation from production code and testing code is subject to an outdated philosophy. I am sure this will change one day but the world is not ready yet ;).

Comment: @kerner As said: well. My philosophy is called *clean code*. And it boils down to: you have **exactly** those things in your production code that need to be there to get the job done. I enhanced my last paragraph again on that. And: nice talking to you ;-)

Comment: @GostCat I agree on your philosophy. It needs to be as *clean as possible*. And it needs to *get the job done*, and this is the strongest requirement. To do so, test code is (unfortunately) necessary, I think we all agree on that. Test code separates idealistic models from reality. It is a big challenge to integrate testing into concepts of clean code but I think it can be done and it needs to be done. Nice talking to you too :)

Comment: Nice reading on this topic: [How Google Tests Software](https://books.google.de/books/about/How_Google_Tests_Software.html?id=vHlTOVTKHeUC&redir_esc=y)

Comment: I have a situation right now where I can make some production code that forms a SQL query more efficient by making an assumption about some state that's known at compile time, but might change in the future.  My choices are 1) verify the assumption in the production code at runtime and throw an IllegalStateException if it's violated, OR 2) create an automated test that does the same.  I like option 2, because I don't incur any runtime cost in production for doing the verification.  I want to link to the test in the production code JavaDoc.

Comment: @GhostCat I would say it depends ;) For a little project I went API first and made an abstract test class which defines the contract implementations of the API should adhere to. The issue I have right now is that as it seems things like maven or alike don't like "production" classes (API) refering to test classes (contract).

Comment: @jpitt42 Your use case sounds very similar to what I would like to do.

Comment: @ViToni FWIW, I chose to do a verification of the assumption in code where it throws an IllegalStateException AND also have an automated test that catches this condition.  The in-code verification is not very costly in my case (4 lookups in a small HashSet); especially compared to the cost of the more complicated SQL query.

Comment: @jpitt42 Thanks for the answer.

What I meant is actually the JavaDoc part ;)
Currently I have the issue that Maven does not want to create my JavaDoc because of the reference to the test class...

Comment: @ViToni yes.  I tried doing the same as you, which brought me here.  I was just noting what I did instead since the JavaDoc link from production code to test code is not supported.